# Im new in the development of AR, Can you integrate Augmented Reality into Machine Learning/Image Processing into a single mobile application

Tags: augmented-reality, arcore

Im new in the development of AR and I want to develop an Augmented Reality Application integrated with Image Processing/ Machine Learning Features

I already developed a program for the Image Processing and now i want to integrate it with Augmented Reality

anyone have ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. There are several project teams doing this at the moment. See this repo for an example of how to implement ML with ARCore: https://github.com/googlesamples/arcore-ml-sample